# Casting Errors on getting datetime value from db using Linq in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to get the datetime value from the table using some where conditions but it is giving exception as : ***LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.***

***Linq Query what i'm trying :***

```
Datetime PDate=(from p in db.PMaster
                      where p.ID == ID
                      && p.PNumber == Num
                      select p.PDate).SingleOrDefault();
```

I'm trying to get Datetime column(PDate) value from the the db using linq and assigning it to variable.

What i'm doing wrong??

Comment: @TimSchmelter...its a datetime column mentioned in question

Comment: where do you use the `PDate`?

Comment: what if you try this ` db.PMaster.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: You're sure this is *all* the code that's causing the problem? I can't see any indexing here, which is odd... what's the compile-time type of `db.PMaster`?

Comment: @Tim.Tang-Thanks making db.PMaster as db.PMaster.AsEnumerable() solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Please, either add your own answer and mark as valid, or delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Based on **@Tim.Tang** comment, following code snippet solved my problem

```
Datetime PDate=(from p in db.PMaster.AsEnumerable()
                      where p.ID == ID
                      && p.PNumber == Num
                      select p.PDate).SingleOrDefault();
```